# Inverse of function tf.gather()

Tags: python, tensorflow

Suppose I have a tensor `a` of shape `[B,D]`, and I have a list `I` containing indices of shape `[B]`. Now I want to extend the tensor to the shape `[M,D]` with `M > B` using indices in the list. Note that the indices belong to the range `[0,M]`. Concretely, `I` is the mapping of rows from the tensor `a` to another tensor that has larger value for dimension `0`. This functionality is opposite to the function `tf.gather()`.
Could someone suggest a solution?
Thanks

Comment: tf.scatter_nd et al. and tf.zeros/tf.fill

Answer (score 1):

`tf.scatter_nd` is the reverse of `tf.gather_nd`. Lets see that with a round trip example where:

- First we create a tensor of shape `((5,4,1,2,3))` where all elements are zero except elements at indices `[1,2,0,0]` and `[3,0,0,1]`, which are `[16, 12, 11]` and `[3,0,0,1]` respectively, using `tf.scatter_nd`.
- Second, we do the reverse by applying the `tf.gather_nd` on the generated tensor to get the two original vectors, i.e., `[16, 12, 11]` and `[3,0,0,1]`.

```
updates = [[16, 12, 11],[18, 40, 37]]
indices = [[1,2,0,0], [3,0,0,1]]
shape = (5,4,1,2,3)

# first step - scatter
scat_tensor = tf.scatter_nd(indices=indices, updates=updates, shape=shape)
print(f"verification: expected {updates[0]}, got {scat_tensor[1,2,0,0]}")

# now the reverse step
reconstructed_updates = tf.gather_nd(scat_tensor, indices)
print(f"verification: expected {updates }, got {reconstructed_updates }")
```